# Telerik GridView - Making a column span a row. Can it be done?

Tags: c#, css, gridview, telerik, telerik-grid

Good morning SO, I have a two part question

I have a Telerik RadGrid that looks like this:

[image]

As noted that constitutes an entire "ROW".

I want to try and re-position the "Title" column to expand the entire row like this:

[image]

yet remain part of one "row" of data.

I have been told this is entirely impossible which comes as a surprise to me since I believe RadGrid renders as HTML elements? How should I be able to accomplish this?

My second question is that I want to "separate" rows or put "spacing" in-between rows how can I accomplish this feat? Via CSS?

Thank you.

Comment: There is no built in way to do it, because what you want wouldn't make sense for most applications.  Generally, you would have multiple rows, so naturally, the grid view wouldn't know which one to take as the header.

However, it should be possible, if you can post your view and viewmodel code.

Comment: Actually, I think I misunderstood your question after reading it again.  However, I'm sure there is still a way to work around it if you can post the code.

Comment: @WyattEarp I can post code later on I'm mobile right now. 
But essentially what looks like "headers" are actually going to be part of the columns.  There will be no headers. Everything would be in a column. 
Title is a column spanning the entirety of the row followed by the remaining columns beneath it. Does this help?

Comment: @WyattEarp is one of my childhood Heros. I'm actually married to a related member of Doc Holiday lol.